# Windows Authentication not working in existing asp.net site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.5

I have an existing asp.net site that I want to modify to use Windows authentication (It is on a local intranet.)

I have modified the web.config file to use Windows Auth:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
 </authorization>
 <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

The error message that I get is:

```
401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.
```

If I remove: `<deny users="?"/>`  Then the page is shown.  However this code shows that although the User is not null, the user is not logged in:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }
```

What I have tried:

In Visual Studio, if I create a new MVC App, and select "Windows Authentication" it works as expected, and the user is logged in with the domain name.

Reducing the project to just the web.config and a single aspx page still works.  But when I try to use the same exact web.config in an existing project (Or a new empty project) I get the same error.

So there must be some other setting somewhere that needs to be set, but I cannot determine what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/216/Windows-Authentication-With-ASP.NET-Web-Pages)

In Visual Studio, select the Project in the Solution Explorer, then press <kbd>F4</kbd> to view the project properties. Note: These properties are on a **side** window (typically) not the main (center) window.

Set: 
1) Windows Authentication to Enabled and 
2) Anonymous Authentication to Disabled.

Comment: This is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043140/windows-authentication-doesnt-works-when-i-run-project-from-visual-studio