# JetBrain Rider , Access denied when using IIS Express with Windows Authentication

Tags: windows-authentication, iis-express, rider

I have an enabled Windows Authentication on my projects. When I run it from Rider, it always prompts me "access denied". It's working fine when I run it via Visual Studio.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried running Rider as administrator

Comment: I am having the same issue. It appears that IIS express is allowing anonymous access to the website. I'm looking into configuring it to force auth.

Comment: Cant you provide your web.config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigate to: `<project>.idea/config/applicationhost.config`

Find the tag `<authentication>` and enable the `<windowsAuthentication>` tag like so: `<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">`

Mine looks like this:

```xml
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <add value="Negotiate" />
        <add value="NTLM" />
    </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

Comment: Cool, it works Thanks! But why Rider doesn't respect the web.config, I wonder

Comment: This is now in the `.vs/config/` settings, so they followed suit putting it in the `.idea/config/` settings https://stackoverflow.com/a/49530114/3018212

Answer (score 5):

## Work-in-progress by JetBrains, see [issue RIDER-15230](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-15230)

Just to build on [@RyanDawkins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594657) with a **GUI equivalent**.

### Steps

1. *Right-click* the Project the web app launches from
2. Select Properties ...
3. In the Modal, under Properties > Web there is a *checkbox* for *Windows authentication*

### Screenshot

[image]

This is similar to the Visual Studio way of doing things, it just saves the settings in `{SolutionFolder}/.idea/config` instead of `{SolutionFolder}/.vs/config`

Answer (score 0):

In `<project>.idea/config/applicationhost.config`
I had to do two things:
Set: `<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">`
Set: `<anonymousAuthentication enabled="false">`