# Project Rider doesn't read launchSettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, rider

I am using Project Rider 2017.3 to build Asp.Net core 2.x project. When I run project in visual studio 2017 it gets environment variables from launchSettings.json but Project Rider doesn't load variables from same file. I have to go to edit configurations and add environment variables manually.

Is there anyway to force Rider to read variables from launchSettings.json ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, launcherSettings.json is a Visual Studio specific file and any other UIs may or may not use it. It's **not** required for the deployed application neither it's used by `dotnet` cli tools

Comment: @Tseng, unfortunately Rider is trying to clone the relevant part (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560884/jetbrain-rider-access-denied-when-using-iis-express-with-windows-authenticatio), so some day they will support `launchSettings.json` as well. Generally speaking, this file is not restricted to VS, and any IDE should be able to utilize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for `launchSettings.json` has been added in 2018.3.

More info on how it works is available at https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2018/11/08/using-net-core-launchsettings-json-rundebug-apps-rider/

Answer (score 0):

in my case, Rider did not read launchSettings.json because there was invalid JSON (an extra comma), while Visual Studio read this file