# healthchecks-ui windows authentication .net core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, health-check

I'm trying to implement HealthChecks to a .net core 3.1 project. The endpoint works fine and returns a valid json.

The problem is when trying to add a ui to the health checks using [AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/).

It also works fine until I change the settings of the project to windows authentication. When I do that I get the following error:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line
> 0, position 0.

How can I get the UI to work with windows authentication?

Comment: How are you changing your project to windows auth? This error is usually related to a `web.config` slipup.

Comment: Debug tab in the properties of the project in visual studio 2019

Comment: Did you host your application on IIS or Self-Host? I found that if you start application in Visual Studio with `windows authentication` you need to do the following steps in [disscussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043140/windows-authentication-doesnt-work-when-i-run-project-from-visual-studio)

Comment: windows authentication works fine, Health checks ui with windows authentication doesn't work